# Runtime error attaching Pdf file attachment in Outlook

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

This code for automated email with Pdf attachment is working in several laptops but not working in my laptop. I am using same version of Excel and Windows.

```vb
Sub SendWorksheet_AsPDFAttachment_OutlookEmail()
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim strTempFile As String
    Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
 
    'Specify the worksheet name
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O36").Select
 
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTempFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value
 
    'export the specific worksheet as PDF
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strTempFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'Call SaveAsPDF_Click
    'Create a new email
    
    Dim rng As Range
    'Dim imagerange As Range
    
    Set rng = Worksheets("Email Body").Range("A3:I23").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set imagerange = Worksheets("Email Body").Range("A26:I45").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objMail.Subject = "Letter of Appreciation from Office of CGPD"
 objMail.To = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B49").Value
    'Attach the PDF file
    objMail.Attachments.Add strTempFile
   
    objMail.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    'objMail.Display '==>display this email
    objMail.send '==>to send this email
    'Delete the temp PDF file
    objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add Error occurs in debug at below code   objMail.Attachments.Add strTempFile

Comment: When using `strTempFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value`, does the cell in discussion contain 'pdf' extension ? I would try searching for this specific file, where it should be saved and see how its real name looks... Is it exactly the one kept by `strTempFile` variable?

Comment: =CONCATENATE("Letter  - ",'Deatils Sheet'!B2,".pdf") is the formula on B50 when is see strTempFile - file name appears as Letter -Raja.Pdf

Comment: Did you see such a newly created file? If yes, where are you looking for? It is saved in the current directory, but I am afraid that the attachment need the full path. I would suggest you to fully qualify the path. I would try `strTempFile = thisWorbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value`. Try in this way, please.

Comment: file name i saw on the Debug mode by placing the Mouse pointer on strTempfile.. I am not used to codes.. Sorry if my language troubles you. I will try your code

Comment: Great.. after making the change the code is working

Comment: Glad I could help! I will transform the comments in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of **Attachment full path necessity**...

If `strTempFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value` does not contain the path, `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat` will work and it will create the file in the **current directory**.

`objMail.Attachments.Add strTempFile` **needs the full qualified file path**.

So, `strTempFile` must be fully qualified. I mean, try the next approach:

```
strTempFile = thisWorbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B50").Value
```

If it will work, you can find any other temporary path (Temp, Documents etc.)